# How are "plot" and "story" different from each other?

Tags: word-usage

I know these words are interchangeable to roughly mean story.

What I am interested to know here is that how different is "plot" compared to "story"? If there is any differences.

My dictionary says that plot means the main events of a play, novel, movie, or similar work, devised and presented by the writer as an interrelated sequence.

So It sounds like the word *plot* is more high level word than *story* and the word *story* has broader meaning than the word *plot*, but I would like some confirmation on that.

Comment: You owe it to the community to at least look up the words [plot](http://www.onelook.com/?w=plot) and [story](http://www.onelook.com/?w=story) in a dictionary, and do a few basic searches on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=plot+vs+story) before asking here. Maybe you've done some of that already; if so, you need to share what you found here in the body of your question. Otherwise, people here will simply scramble doing those same things, and give you either (a) answers you could have easily found yourself, or (b) answers you already know. A few examples might help, too.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the [Wikipedia explanation of plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plot_(narrative)) more helpful. A plot, in the sense that you mean it, is a part of certain types of stories. An author may create the plot before actually writing a story to explain to someone else what she intends to write or as sort of an outline to assist her in writing the story.

This may be a strange illustration, but the [Angry Alien Productions](http://www.angryalien.com/) website has "30-second Bunnies Theatre" videos in which the plot of a full length movie is re-enacted in 30 seconds. The movie is the story, and the 30 second re-enactment is the plot (or at least as many of the most memorable parts of the plot that will fit into 30 seconds).

A story may be fictional or not. A plot is a sequence of events planned by the author of a story. A plot could be based on a non-fictional story, but it is usually manipulated to make the story more compelling or dramatic.

I could tell stories about my trip to Europe that don't have a plot - they are just events that happened to me as I was travelling. If I wrote a play based on my trip to Europe, I would probably create a plot using those events that would give them more meaning and link them together so that my audience would stay interested. I might omit some things that happened because they aren't important to the plot of the story that I want to tell.

Answer (score 0):

A **plot** is one element of a story, which also includes other elements such as characters, dialogue, etc. and each of these elements might be evaluated relatively independently from the others.